# mysql_real_escape_string() function for $user In PhP script, swears demanding to do how to fix it?

Tags: php

In this part requires to replace it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wallets WHERE id = '$user' LIMIT 1";
```

Requires to do this: use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function for the `$user` parameter

How to implement it?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wallets WHERE id = '$user' LIMIT 1";
```

Eliminate vulnerability!

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not enough. Read about parameterized queries. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/11127709

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated. See [this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should upgrade the code from the `mysql` extension to `mysqli` or `PDO`, and then use parametrized queries. The `mysql` extension was deprecated years ago, and has been removed entirely from PHP 7.

But if you're still using this extension, you can do:

```
$user_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wallets WHERE id = '$user_esc' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I suppose people would be more willing to upvote, if you showed an example of the proper way to do it without archaic functions.